# jquerymobile file input text is invisible on android 3.2 browser

Tags: android, html, jquery-mobile, file-upload, file-io

I'm using `<input type="file">` in a jquerymobile web application.
It works good on several platforms, but on samsung galaxy tab 10" (Android 3.2) file input filename is not visible after file was selected.
After some investigations I've found that removing data-position="fixed" almost fix the problem (input text is visible but shifted down).

Here is my test html.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.css" />
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js"></script>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="panel" id="leftpanel">
            left panel
        </div>

        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <h1>Test item</h1>
            <a href="#leftpanel" data-role="button" data-inline="true">left panel</a>
        </div>    

        <div data-role="content">
            <input type="file" data-clear-btn="true" id="file1">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade to jquerymobile 1.4.0 Beta fixed the problem.